# Basic python; ' in text variable which stops my script; psycopg&tweepy; python, postgres and twitter

Tags: python, string, postgresql, text, tweepy

I have a script that mines tweets and inputs them into my postgres database. It works for most messages

With the following line I can return the text of a message:

```
tweet.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Whenever the tweet has a ' in the text my script stops. I could make a function that extracts the tweet and puts it within two ". But I figured I will get the same problem when a tweet contains a ". Then I could make a function that checks tweets on containing a ' or " and catch these statements off. But it seems way to much work for this simple problem.

So i'd like to know how to overcome this problem without to much scripting effort.

I am not an expert in python and one of the things that is my problem is that I try to fix things in a difficult way while there often is a much simpler way. The current problem made me think this is a scenario like that. Hence, my question here.

*** UPDATE

My error pops up when inserting the message into my postgres table indeed.

I just tried repr() but still got a similar error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...python.py", line 28, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(userid, created, retweets, message) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')".format(tweet.user.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.retweet_count, ber))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "E19"
LINE 1: ...LUES('1251822199', '2016-02-27 10:23:40', '0', 'b'E19 (A1) M...
```

The 4th parameter is the text of the tweet and starts with 'b'E19 as text. It fails here.

The line I use to input the data into postgres is the following:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(message) VALUES('{0}')".format(repr(tweet.text.encode('utf-8'))))
```

Comment: Use the [repr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function?

Comment: Any errors? Post the traceback if there is one. Also where is the failure? Presumably when performing the Postgres query, but you should make that clear. And a sample of the input might be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are manually creating the query with string operations, you would need to escape the quotes in the query.

But a better way is to use parameterised queries and allow `psycopg2` to perform escaping of special characters. This will also make your code less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if some of the parameters are from untrusted sources, e.g. a user.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(message) VALUES(%s)", (tweet.text.encode('utf-8'),))
```

or

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(userid, created, retweets, message) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (tweet.user.id, tweet.created_at, tweet.retweet_count, ber))
```

Now the DB layer will perform escaping for you.

Comment: Thank you. My script runs now. I only encountered another problem which probably is caused by the encoding of the text message. All my messages in the table in postgres look like this \x344262455 (and a lot more numbers) . 

When I print the same statement I use to insert the message into postgres it does give me a nice print of the message.

Comment: When I do not encode tweet.text.encode('utf-8') and just use tweet.text it does work. Thank you for the help! I guess I encode it in postgres now instead of in python. And I assume postgres decodes the encoded version of python and that causes the weird messages.

Comment: Postgres is probably storing your data in UTF8 encoding. Check the encoding by logging into postges with `psql` and issuing the `\l` command. You can also check the client encoding with `\encoding`. You can ditch the explicit UTF8 conversion and just pass  `tweet.text` as your query parameter.